# When VueDatePicker and USelectMenu from @nuxthq/ui are used in the same page they freeze browser (chromium but no firefox)

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

## VueDatePicker and USelectMenu conflict

I installed packages

```
"dependencies": {
    "@vuepic/vue-datepicker": "^5.4.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.17.3",
    "@nuxt/devtools": "latest",
    "@nuxthq/ui": "^2.7.0",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^6.8.0",
    "nuxt": "^3.6.5"
}
```

There is my nuxt config

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    css: ['@vuepic/vue-datepicker/dist/main.css'],
    devtools: {enabled: true},
    modules: ['@nuxthq/ui'],
    build: {
        transpile: ['@vuepic/vue-datepicker']
    }
})
```

and app.vue component

```js
<script setup>
import VueDatePicker from '@vuepic/vue-datepicker';

const people = ['Wade Cooper', 'Claudie Smith', 'Emil Schaefer']
const selected = ref(people[0])

const date = ref();
</script>

<template>
  <USelectMenu v-model="selected" :options="people"/>
  <VueDatePicker v-model="date"/>
</template>
```

If I remove one of these components, the page works, but these two present at the same time on the page crashing it.

I observed also that if in a project there are more pages, then if you visit the page without these components and use `router-ling` to go on this page it works, so a problem is only when you open the page with these components on it typing URL in the address bar and clicking ENTER.

Also, if you remove these components and add them when your page is open, these work correctly thanks to HMR.

What was most surprising for me I am not able to reproduce this problem on Firefox, but see it in Chrome and Chromium on 2 machines.

After a long time of loading, I finally see:

```
Page Unresponsive
You can wait for it to become responsive of exit the page.
```

Can you reproduce it, or know how to fix it?

Link to GitHub with minimal example https://github.com/gustawdaniel/daisyui-nuxtui-conflict-reproduction